# Local Docker Image Status UP (unhealthy) does not get displayed in the control center

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-kafka-connect, plc4x

im trying to create a local image that extends the confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:latest image with the apache-kafka-connect-plc4x-plc4j-0.10.0 connector. Therefore i followed the steps of the local image creation from confluent: https://docs.confluent.io/5.4.2/connect/managing/extending.html
After this i exchanged the image in my docker-compose file though the extended Version which includes the PLC4X connector

My Dockerfile, for creating the local image looks like this:

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:latest

\# Copy the PLC4X Connect adapter to the appropriate directory

COPY apache-kafka-connect-plc4x-plc4j-0.10.0.zip /tmp/apache-kafka-connect-plc4x-plc4j-0.10.0.zip

RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt /tmp/apache-kafka-connect-plc4x-plc4j-0.10.0.zip
```

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:7.1.2
    networks:
      - test-network
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
      - "29092:29092"
      - "29093:29093"


    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST://:9092,EXTERNAL_DIFFERENT_HOST://:29093,INTERNAL://broker:29092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://broker:29092,EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST://localhost:9092,EXTERNAL_DIFFERENT_HOST://157.245.80.232:29093
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL_DIFFERENT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'

  connect:
    #image: cnfldemos/cp-server-connect-datagen:0.5.3-7.1.0
    image: connect-plc4x:1.2
    networks:
      - test-network
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry

    ports:
      - "8083:8083"

    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081

      # CLASSPATH required due to CC-2422

      CLASSPATH: /usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-7.1.2.jar
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: /usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR
```

With the Standard Image everything works fine, when i use the new local image, the Status is UP(unhealthy( and i cant use the connector section of the confluent control-center. I'm happy about every tip or suggestion

#### Update regarding comment

this is the configuration of my control center:

```
   control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:7.3.2
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
      - connect
      - ksqldb-server
    ports:
      - "9021:9021"
    environment:
        CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
        CONTROL_CENTER_CONNECT_CONNECT-DEFAULT_CLUSTER: 'http://connect:8083'
        CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_URL: "http://ksqldb-server:8088"
        CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_ADVERTISED_URL: "http://localhost:8088"
        CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
        CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
        CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
        CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
        CONTROL_CENTER_CONNECT_HEALTHCHECK_ENDPOINT: '/connectors'
        CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
        PORT: 9021
```

Comment: What status are you referring to? `docker compose ps`? Did you actually build your new container?

Comment: Yes its the status of docker compose ps. I build the container by exchanging the Image of my connect container to connect-plc4x:1.2 and apply the change with docker compose up -d.

Comment: That doesn't build anything. You need to manually run `docker build -t connect-plc4x:1.2`

Comment: sorry my bad, yes of course. I already did this. When i check the logs with `docker logs connect` the Connector instances are up and running. I think the main problem is that the connectos are not displayed in the confluent control center.

Comment: Okay, sure. Can you share your Control Center configuration, then?